# Vizualisation tool for Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-visualization

I am a new Cassandra user. I am searching for a visualization tool (open-source or licensed) that I can use to build visualization (graph, etc.) based on data stored in a Cassandra server ?

I am not sure whether such tool exists, but it would be nice if it would allow to have OLAP style visualization. By that I mean the user would be able to select which data he wants to include or not in the graph...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we have below GUI tools for interacting with Cassandra Cluster.

**Cassandra Cluster Admin** – Similar to phpMyAdmin for MySQL, this graphical administration tool features a simple interface that can display Cassandra data in columns, rows, and range slices. It allows for keyspace, column family, and row manipulation.

**OpsCenter** – Provided by DataStax, OpsCenter is a complete data infrastructure management tool allowing you to manage, monitor and control Cassandra. It provides a wide range of visualization to help you see exactly what is going on with your databases.

**Cassandra GUI 2.0** – Specifically designed to make management easier, this graphical tool for cassandra features a row view explorer and filtering of displayable data. This current version is only for viewing data and not for manipulation.

**Helenos** – This tool allows for exploring data and managing schema. You can add/remove/truncate column families, add/drop a keyspace, view paginated results and offer both administrative and read-only roles for users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I am not looking at tools that target the developers instead I am searching for the ones that can be put into the end-users hands. Most probably they will not know that the data are is coming from Cassandra